# Listen new media files and upload those files in background

Tags: android, android-studio, service

I want to create an application which can listen new media files and upload those media files in background. I need the best possible ways of creating  such service. It shouldn't be killed. The service should be running untill user take an action on the event. I need the best suggestions as code or any reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let us know how you have implemented till now then someone can provide suggestion on top of it.